# How to override ToString() method?

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code (edited for brevity), I want to override the behaviour of the `.ToString()` method.  Using "`override`" only tells me that "no suitable method was found to override".  If I use "`new`", it compiles and builds OK, but the code never uses the new `ToString()`.  It just continues to use the native .NET `.ToString()` method.

Any idea what's wrong?

```
public class Form_Processor {

    public Form_Processor() {

        SqlDataReader rs;
        
        //SNIP database query

        while (rs.Read()) {

                result = rs["ReportDateTime"].ToString("dd");
        }
        
        rs.Close();
        
    }
    
    // **********************************************************
    
    public new string ToString(string strFormat) {

        if (strFormat != null) {
            return "OK";
        }

        return null;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why should the returning object of `rs["ReportDateTime"]` know about your overriden method in your class `Form_Processor`?

Comment: [`string ToString(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable.tostring) and [`string ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) are two different method signatures. Only the latter needs to be marked with `override`

Comment: You need to override `ToString()`, not `ToString(string strFormat)`

Comment: I would expect there's no available override *with the `strFormat` argument*.  Did you try overriding just `ToString()`?  Why is `strFormat` there at all?  (Side notes: The constructor shown is irrelevant and unnecessary for a [mcve].  You could, however, provide an example of how you're calling `.ToString()` on an instance of *this* class.  Or were you expecting `rs["ReportDateTime"].ToString("dd")` to invoke this class' `.ToString()`?  If so, that expectation is simply wrong. Additionally, performing database I/O *in a constructor* is very likely to be a bad idea.)

Comment: This is not how overriding works. The override needs to be defined in the same class on which it is called. What are you trying to do? There is probably a better solution if you give us more context.

Comment: Oh dear, there are so many problems in these 10 lines of code, it's unbelievable. Hard to tell where one would even start. Please ask a colleague to help you out fixing all the stuff in that code. You may ask for 2 hours.

Comment: `public override string ToString() {`. Side note: among other issues, the `rs.Close();` is wrong, you should have a `using`

Comment: The code is for demo purposes only.  It's condensed from working code that works just fine - except for the ToString() bit.

Comment: @KWallace: And what "doesn't work" about `ToString()` here?  Throughout the question you describe overriding and using `ToString()`, but in the code shown you are trying to override `ToString(string strFormat)`.  Which is it?  In the code shown you're also not *using* the `ToString(string strFormat)` method.  But if you *think* you are, that's a different issue entirely.  It would be worth clarifying in the question with a [mcve] and specific indication of expected vs. observed behavior.

Comment: charlieface: Negative.  The code is correct "as is" due to the way the resultset is opened: (`CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`)

Comment: I def "got it" that the signatures are different.  I may not be able to do this?

Comment: @KWallace: "Be able to do" *what*, specifically?  You certainly can't override a method which doesn't exist in the inherited class.  So what, specifically, are you trying to accomplish in the code shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I suspect you're trying to apply [Custom String Formatting](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6533/Custom-String-Formatting-in-NET). To do that, try implementing `IFormattable`.

```
void Main()
{
    object foo = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine($"{foo:dd}"); // output: OK
    Console.WriteLine(((IFormattable)foo).ToString("dd", null)); // output: OK
}


public class Foo : IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
    {
        if (format != null)
        {
            return "OK";
        }

        return "Not OK";
    }
}
```

Comment: That is, in fact, exactly what I am trying to do.  Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ToString()` and `ToString(string strFormat)` are two different methods. `ToString(string)` is an overload and not an override of `ToString()`.

The error message "no suitable method was found to override" is correct. `Form_Processor` is implicitly derived from `Object` and there is an `Object.ToString()` method but there is no `ToString(string)` overload on `Object`.

To override `ToString()` use `public override string ToString() ...`.

Comment: Will the override of ToString() still work with formatters?  .ToString("MMdd"), for example.

Comment: `Object.ToString()` doesn't accept a format string. But see @StriplingWarrior's answer about `IFormattable`. Also see @David's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
rs["ReportDateTime"].ToString("dd")
```

Has nothing to do with this:

```
public new string ToString(string strFormat) {
```

You're trying to override `ToString(string strFormat)` on your `Form_Processor` class.  Which, in the absense of an explicit inherited class, inherits from `Object`.  Which [has no such method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object).

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader), `rs` here is of type `Object`.  Your class *inherits* from `Object`, but `Object` itself has nothing to do with your class.

If your goal is to apply a format string for this operation:

```
rs["ReportDateTime"].ToString("dd")
```

Then overall it sounds like overriding was simply the wrong approach and ended up confusing you.  If the goal is for this class to have a method which can be used to format values within this class, why not just... write a method for that?  For example:

```
public string FormatString(object obj, string strFormat) {
    // your "ToString" logic for "obj"
}
```

And to use it:

```
FormatString(rs["ReportDateTime"], "dd")
```

You can override `ToString()` (or add a `ToString(string strFormat)`) in your class which would be used when calling that method *on an instance of your class*.  But that's simply not what the code is doing.

Comment: This is the approach I was leaning towards, but really just wanted to be able to fine-tune the formatting inside .ToString().  Specifically, to have it return an empty string when it cannot format the string with the given formatter instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @KWallace: All of which can be done within the non-`ToString` method, and none of which really relies on or is in any way related to method overriding.  It's not clear what led you to use method overriding to accomplish this task, other than either (1) a misunderstanding of objects and inheritance in general or (2) a mispresentation of the intent in the question.

Comment: Go with the former.  ;-)